# Short Drop Shadows - Monogame/HLSL

Tags: xna, shader, shadow, monogame, hlsl

I'm trying to find a method to implement angled drop shadows for my sprites in my game. That is, I want objects like my player, trees, etc to have shadows based on a sun's position in the sky.

The shadows in this game (Gangs of Asia) for example:
[image]

I have tried modifying Catalin Zima's method to fit my needs with little success, ultimately I don't think this approach will work for me, and the optimizations he does are a little over my head at the moment. I describe my struggles [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799439/shadowing-blocked-hlsl-xna).

I've spent some time learning HLSL the past few weeks, doing some simple ambient light and color changing shaders, but am honestly at a loss as to how to approach this requirement.

Can anyone recommend an approach or supply some resources? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Strom and what is the procedure used in the screenshot?

Comment: I don't see how this fits the XY problem. Specifically, I think you are talking about the linked post in the question, which maybe fits that form a little better. However this question is asking for resources or thoughts about how to implement dynamic lighting and shadowing. @Strom why shouldn't I take this approach in your opinion? What is wrong with dynamic lighting?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with dynamic lighting. It is hard to implement properly in a 2D environment.(In 3D, once occlusion is established this becomes a simple term in the lighting equation).  In 2D, there is no height component, therefore all shadows rely on the perceived projection of the object onto the perceived ground plane.  In the screenshot, the shadows are pre-generated using 3D models and applied to the surfaces around the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I don't think these are actual shadows but rather the sprite rendered a bit distorted.

After you've rendered the background (floor), you render all sprites with black or dark gray color. But you skew the polygon a bit to the left:
[image]

Then you render the sprite as normal at the same location. Now you have a nice looking shadow effect which is also a super fast method.
[image]

The only think you have to take into account is when the character is jumping. You have to offset the shadow sprite render. Preferably by having a vector pointing to the top left and scaling it by the height of the jump.